# Copy the file with folder structure from Linux to Windows using WinSCP and delete file which ever is copied and keep the folder

Tags: powershell, winscp

PowerShell or WinSCP – need to download the file and folder structure and delete the file which ever is copied and delete the file but not folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with [WinSCP .NET assembly and a PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

```
$result = $session.GetFilesToDirectory($remotePath, $localPath)
$result.Check()

foreach ($result.Transfers as $transfer)
{
    $session.RemoveFile($transfer.FileName)
}
```

---

An alternative approach, that deletes each file individually right after it is downloaded, is shown in this article:
[Recursively move files in directory tree to/from SFTP/FTP server while preserving source directory structure](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_moves_files_keeping_directory_structure#download)